# Is it possible to create an array and push content in one step

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Is there a more concise (i.e. one line) way to do this in Javascript?:

```
    //Media object hasn't been declared yet

    var mediaObject.tags = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mediaObject.tags.push(entries[i]);
    }
```

**EDIT: Here is how my full function looks**

```
var mediaObject = new CustomMedia();
        mediaObject.text = entries[k]['text'];
        mediaObject.tags = [];
        for(var i = entries[k]['tags'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mediaObject.tags.push(entries[k]['tags'][i]['value']);
        }
```

The last part is what I want to make into one line. Declaring the `mediaObject.tags` and `pushing` the content.

Comment: if `mediaObjects.tags` is an array and `entries` is an array, is there any reason why you are not doing `mediaObjects.tags = entries`?

Comment: @blurfus Because he doesn't want to push all elements  from one array to another.

Comment: I did not infer that from the question (I supposed the example does hint at only copying the first 100 entries).  Is that why OP?

Comment: What is `mediaObject.tags`?

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Variables can't have `.` in the name.

Comment: I am not making `mediaObjects.tags = entries` because I wanted that array to contain a subset of properties.

@cookiemonster thank you for pointing that out.

The full function was:

`var new MediaObject();
for(i =  0; i < entries.length; i++){
    MediaObject.id = entries[i]['id'];
    //Here's where I wanted to add the tags array
}`

Comment: This isn't a legal JS declaration: `var mediaObject.tags = [];`.  If `mediaObject` already exists, then you can just do `mediaObject.tags = [];` without the `var`.  If `mediaObject` doesn't exist, then you have to first declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you need is [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
mediaObject.tags = entries[k].tags.map(function (t) { return t.value; });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var mediaObject.tags = entries.slice(0, 100);
```

Comment: I think this is almost it, however the values for for `mediaObjects.tags` are nested in two arrays.

Comment: There's probably a `.slice()` somewhere in a good solution, but it isn't the `entries` array that the OP is trying to push into another array (as shown in their 2nd code block after their latest edit) so this is way over simplified and does not actually solve the OP's issue.